# Remove duplicate letters in a string?

Tags: python

How can i make a basic function with def in python that removes duplicate letters from a string?
Example: input: "abbcdddea"; output: "abcdea"

Comment: The same way you remove duplicates from any iterable

Answer (score 0):

This code removes duplicates but conserves the order:

```
string = "abb"
string_without_duplicates = "".join(dict.fromkeys(string))
```